# XMLHttpRequest and C CGI...who sends back just one word

Tags: javascript, c, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a test with a simple form with a script who takes the value of the text area and sends it to "sample.cgi", now, "sample.cgi" should just send back exactly the text I sent to him...but, I get back only the first word.
I can't really find the problem.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function mytest() {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) { 
      //If everything is ok show the output whit an alert
       alert("This is the server answer: " + xhr.responseText);

        }

      };
      var myText = document.getElementById("message").value;
      //Request to "sample.cgi"
      xhr.open("POST", "sample.cgi", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      //Sending the data
      xhr.send(myText);


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>MY TEST: </h2>
  <form>
    <textarea id="message">
    </textarea>
    <button type="button" onclick="mytest()">Request data</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The sample.gci code:

```C
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
 printf("Content-Type: text/plain;\n\n");


 char myText[1000];
 //the data is sent by "POST" method, then we find it in stdin
 fscanf(stdin,"%s", myText);
 printf("%s",myText);

     return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and especially the part about the `"%s"` format which says that it "matches a sequence of **non-whitespace** characters" (emphasis mine).

Comment: ... or just dump `scanf()` and switch to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot I solved using fgets! I didn't think about "mytext" is not formatted data.

I would like to ask another small thing, why I don’t get any result when I change my C code in this:

```C
int main(void)
{
 printf("Content-Type: text/plain;\n\n");

 FILE * pFile;
 pFile = fopen ("sample.txt","w");
 char myText[1000];
 fgets(myText,1000, stdin);
 fprintf(pFile, "%s\n",myText);
 printf("We stored this text: %s",myText);
 fclose(pFile);
     return 0;
}
```

Apparently "xhr.onreadystatechange" don’t even receive the right conditions to send the alert.

Thank you very much for your help!